# Does it hurt Demeter's law when model refers to another model?

Tags: php

I have a global container class:

```
final class Container
{
    /**
     * @return ForumThread
     */ 
    public static function getForumThread()
    {
        if (self::$obj1 === null)
        {
             self::$obj1 = new ForumThread();
        }
        return self::$obj1;
    }

    /**
     * @return ForumPosts
     */ 
    public static function getForumPosts()
    {
        if (self::$obj2 === null)
        {
             self::$obj2 = new ForumPosts();
        }
        return self::$obj2;
    }
}
```

my models:

```
class ForumThread
{
    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function findBadLanguage ($inWhat)
    {
        return (bool)rand(0,1);
    }

    /**
     * @return
     */
    public function add ($threadName)
    {
        if (!$this->findBadLanguage ($threadName))
        {
             INSERT INTO
        }
    }
}

class ForumPost
{
    /**
     * @return
     */
    public function post ($toThreadId, $comment)
    {
        // im talking about this:
        Container::getForumThread()->findBadLanguage($comment);
    }
}
```

I know `findBadLanguage()` should be in another class, but lets suppose thats okay. Lets focus on Container::get****() calls. Is it OK to turn to a global container and get objects from it? Doesnt it hury Demeter's law? (those object must be exists only once, and can be DI-ed)

EDIT: you can regard to the `Container` as a Factory

Comment: You're calling a `non-static` method `statically`. Instead of using the global container you should need to inject the thread in the posts imo

Comment: allright, sorry, fixed :)